# Java Apache Ignite event listner unexpected behavior

Tags: java, events, ignite

I have playing with Ignite Microservice example https://github.com/dmagda/MicroServicesExample. I added an event listner, and explicitly subscribed for a specific cache

data-node-config.xml:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <property name="includeEventTypes">
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVTS_CACHE"/>
    </property>
```

DataNodeStartup.java:

```
ignite.events(ignite.cluster().forCacheNodes("vehicles")).remoteListen(locLsnr, rmtLsnr,
        EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED);
```

But i always have catched unexpected event for another cache "maitenance".

Does the forCacheNodes("vehicles") not work or is my wrong config?

UPDATED:

I'am listening events like this

```
        IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> rmtLsnr = new IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(CacheEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Cache event [name=" + evt.name() + ", newValue : " + evt.newValue() + "]");
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behaviour. If you want to listen for events from a specific cache, you can do that in your remote filter.

Your listener doesn't just listen to events for a specific cache. It listens to all events of the specified type from the nodes where your cache is located, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: You mean i should do filtering inside IgnitePredicate apply(), or  can do it at xml config?

Comment: It's Java code, so it would be in your apply method.

Comment: I would also add that Continuous Queries is likely a better fit for the use case: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries. With CQ you can subscribe to a particular cache and get ordered updates with exactly-once guarantee.